# Add Image in Rich Text in Lightning App Builder

Tags: lightning-app-builder

I'm trying to create a button or import an image into a Rich Text component in Lightning App Builder. In the Rice Text component I only seem to be able to add a link, but there's no way to add an image like in other Rich Text areas on other parts of the website.

I can copy and paste an image, and that works for a little  while, but when I go back later I just get an error image in it's place.

[image]

If I can't do it directly in lightning app builder, is there an easy way to do it with a visualforce page or component instead?